# Applying Euler's trick for the Basel problem to cos leads to a wrong result?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, riemann-zeta

I'm trying to do what Euler did with the $\sin(x)$ for the Basel problem, but for $\cos(x)$. This seems to be leading to an incorrect result.

First, the Taylor series of $\cos(x)$ about $x=0$:

$$\cos(x) = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\dots \tag{1}$$

Next, we can express $\cos(x)$ as a polynomial:

$$\begin{align}\cos(x) = a(x+\frac{\pi}{2})(x-\frac{\pi}{2})(x+\frac{3\pi}{2})(x-\frac{3\pi}{2}) \dots\\
 = a\left(x-\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2\right)\left(x-\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)^2\right) \dots
\end{align}$$
Plugging in $x=0$, we get:

$$a = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{\pi i}{2}\right)^2\left(\frac{3\pi i}{2}\right)^2 \dots}$$
And this gives:

$$\cos(x) = \left(1-\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2}\right)\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)^2}\right)\dots \tag{2}$$

Now, let's compare the coefficients of $x^2$ in equations (1) and (2) gives us:

$$-\frac{1}{2!} = -\left(\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2} + \frac{1}{\left(\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)^2} + \dots\right)$$

This leads to:

$$\frac{\pi^2}{8} = \frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\dots$$

But this is obviously incorrect since that sum on the right is $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You didn't go wrong; that sum on the right is $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I was getting this sum with another method and that had a bug. Instead of deleting the question, I'll add an answer specifying my bug for my own future reference.

Answer (score 1):

This was a mistake on my part. The sum we get in the question is actually correct as Misha pointed out. The alternate method I was using to get the same sum had a bug. I'm adding the correct version here for my own future reference.

We know from the Basel problem:

$$\frac{\pi^2}{6} = \frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\dots$$

Dividing both sides by $2^2$:

$$\frac{\pi^2}{24} = \frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\dots$$

Subtracting the two equations above:

$$\frac{\pi^2}{8} = \frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\dots$$